# A chain 64 meters long whose mass is 20 kilograms is hanging

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

A chain 64 meters long whose mass is 20 kilograms is hanging over the edge of a tall building and does not touch the ground. How much work is required to lift the top 3 meters of the chain to the top of the building? Use that the acceleration due to gravity is 9.8 meters per second squared. Your answer must include the correct units.

Comment: Hi Ryan, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! We don't allow homework-like questions like this where you just ask the question directly; you should narrow it down to focus on a specific physics concept first. See our [FAQ#questions] and [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

$$
W =\int^b_a \! F \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

This is the relationship between work and force, you'll need to work out what the force might be. Where a and b are the positions where you are moving from and to against the force.

If you've never done integration before
$$
\int^b_a \! f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(b) - f(a)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The density of the chain is $ \rho = \frac{20}{64} $. The amount of work is made with respect to the force $ F=mg $, but the mass is changing according how far the chain is lifted.

I think the answer is $ \rho g \int_{0}^{3}(64-x)dx $, since the work done (absolute value) is $ W= \int_{a}^{b}F.dx $

Answer (score 0):

Since the gravity is uniform and the chain is freely suspended, we just need to consider the change in height and the change in potential energy.

$$W = \Delta P.E. = mg(h_2 - h_1) $$